# biopython import in Enthought Python Distribution?

Tags: python, biopython, enthought

I am using the [Enthought Python Distribution](https://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php) v7.0-2 (32-bit) and I am having trouble importing biopython. Does anyone know how to import biopython in EPD? I can import other libraries like numpy, matplotlib, etc. with no problem, but `import biopython` is not recognized. What's going on?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
import Bio
```

The tutorial documentation is a good place to get started learning about Biopython:

http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc6